# Dominated Strategy

Tags: game-theory

I have a question about dominated strategy. I understand that dominated strategy is one which is dominated by another strategy. For instance if we have strategy L and H for a single player and if all payoffs of L are lower than that of H then we say L is "dominated" by H.

What if we have a situation where two of L's strategies are lower than that of H's but one of them is the same? e.g. 
$$L: 10, 2, 0 $$
$$H: 10, 5, 2, $$

We can see that $5>2$ and $2>0$ but $10=10$.

In this case, do we say that L is dominated by H? Or all payoffs need to be strictly greater for it to be considered dominated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ***strictly* dominated strategies** and ***weakly* dominated strategies**.

**Strictly dominated strategies** have payoffs *always lower* (i.e. "$<$") than another strategy that dominates it.

**Weakly dominated strategies** have payoffs *always no higher* (i.e. "$\le$") than another strategy that dominates it.

You example features $L$ as a weakly (not strictly) dominated strategy.